# Can we check hibernate criteria alias already exists?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

A few minute ago get an error "duplicate alias" and I started the think about "Can we check alias was already created? alias was already exists."

Do you know about this? Can we check this?

for example :

```
Criteria criteria = getSeession().createCriteria(Example.class,"example");
criteria.createAlias("example.test","test");
```

Now I want this, I'll check if this "test" alias is already created I won't create not I create.

Is that possible? If is that possible how? If Is not possible, Could you offer any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have encountered a similar issue with the complex search criteries. A possible workaround is having an additional criteria building infrastructure to ignore alias duplicates. For an example, using such classes: [Aliases](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/request/aliases/Aliases.java), [Alias](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/request/aliases/Alias.java)    .

```
    Criteria criteria = getSeession().createCriteria(Example.class, "example");

    Aliases aliases = Aliases.create()
        .add("example.test", "test", JoinType.INNER);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("test", "test_value"));

    aliases.addToCriteria(criteria); // add aliases to the criteria

    List<Example> examples = criteria.list();
```

To use `Aliases` class you can just download this library (it doesn't need additional jars): [fluent-hibernate](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate).